# Backing up specific folders to Azure Blob Storage using Duplicity

Tags: azure, duplicity

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 VM running on Microsoft Azure. I also have an Azure Storage account. I am trying to use duplicity to backup a folder from Ubuntu to a subfolder under an azure container.

I am using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/duplicity -v4 --volsize=25 --log-file=/home/<<user_name>>/duplicity-test/logs/duplicity-log.log --full-if-older-than 30D --asynchronous-upload  /home/<<user_name>>/duplicity-test/alf_data azure://bart-test-2/alf_data
```

This fails with error message:

```
Could not create Azure container: The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
```

However, there is no error if I don't specify a subfolder on the Azure URL, like below:

```
/usr/bin/duplicity -v4 --volsize=25 --log-file=/home/<<user_name>>/duplicity-test/logs/duplicity-log.log --full-if-older-than 30D --asynchronous-upload  /home/<<user_name>>/duplicity-test/alf_data azure://bart-test-2
```

But in this latter case, duplicity simply puts the file in the root folder of the Azure container, and not in a subfolder as I want it to.

Is there a way to make Duplicity use a Subfolder within an Azure container?

Thanks
Vipul.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that they do not allow '/' in the path. [This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/765a4d50-983c-4d88-bad4-807cb1a9f7e7/the-requested-uri-does-not-represent-any-resource-on-the-server?forum=windowsazuredata) from the Azure forums says:

> We do not allow '/' in the path i.e. virtual folder under $root. You would have to create the container. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395424.aspx for more details.

I think the subdirectory name is actually unique and you don't need the full path. You can get away with just using the subdirectory name.

Have you tried:

```
/usr/bin/duplicity -v4 --volsize=25 --log-file=/home/<<user_name>>/duplicity-test/logs/duplicity-log.log --full-if-older-than 30D --asynchronous-upload  /home/<<user_name>>/duplicity-test/alf_data azure://alf_data
```